# Win10 somehow overwrote a partition file table with an old copy

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, partition-recovery

I've had something very weird happen:

I have a Win10 install on a SSD, with another 4 disks connected. Then I added a new disk where I copied 2 large folders to, then I turned PC off and unplugged all the disks except the new one, where I installed a new Win 10 from a USB stick. All good so far, new Windows running, installed a few apps, restarted, all ok. Then I turned it off, plugged all the other disks back and booted to my previous Win10 on the SSD.

Then the new disk was missing the new Win10 install, the file table was as before the switch, with only those 2 big folders. Error logs showed some corruption errors and upon next reboot CHKDSK fixed something but it didn't restore the correct partition.

I had nothing important there and I could recover single files if I needed, but this is kinda worrying.

Z68 motherboard with all disks on Intel chipset except for the new one on a Marvell controller.

Any ideas what could have happened?

Comment: Partition tables are not just lost the way you describe, they are not files, you can’t just copy them to another disk; the fact there was corruption speaks volumes, the drive probably seen better days, time to replace it

Comment: The disk is fine, was running Windows and some applications without any problems, SMART data shows no issues either. It's as if a previous shadow copy was restored upon booting back the main Windows on the other disk,

Comment: Shadow Copy is a function of the OS.  The partition table wouldn’t be changed from anything to do with Shadow Copy